# Create react native module and use it in application

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, module

I want to create react-native module for iOS and Android and use it in an application.

I want to use it like a local module, not uploaded to npm.

When i follow the steps described in the official documentation i always have those error on the import of my module into App.js file :

import MyModule from 'react-test-module';

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-test-module'. '/Users/dbellerose/Path/to/My/Module/react-test-module/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-test-modulet` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-test-module';

When i run the iOS application :

Unable to resolve module `react-test-module` from `/Users/Path/To/My/App/App.js`: Module `react-test-module` does not exist in the Haste module map.

The message give me some tips to solve the problem, but it  does not work.

To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

So what do you know what is the good process to create a module and use it in application without uploading the package to npm ?

Best regards,

David

Comment: you should write precise direction to your module file

Comment: ^^ As nerius says, you'll need to link to the file using the directory like `./some_path/module/component.ts` - if you want to use an Alias like '@test_modules/test.module.ts` then let me know and I'll answer for you.

Comment: Hello, what is component.ts file ? I don't have it in my module

Answer (score 0):

Here's some steps I could share with you as a checklist:

1. `yarn global add create-react-native-module`
2. `create-react-native-module MyLibrary`
3. Cd to MyLibrary folder, run `yarn install`
4. Work on your module

To link to your project, you will need to add the following to your package.json  (the path should be wherever your module is sitting at)

```
"react-native-test-module": "file:../", 
"react-native-my-library": "file:../../react-native-my-library/"
```

** Do keep in mind, if you have new methods appended in module. You will need to:

1. Remove node_modules and Pods from your project
2. Re-execute `yarn/npm install` & `pod install`

Hope it helps.